# How to change the app that Facebook redirects to in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm adding Facebook login to my iPhone app and I used an example iPhone app to test it with and I logged in to Facebook from that example app to my Facebook app and it worked. But now when I log in to Facebook via my real iPhone app, after successful login, it always redirects me to my example iPhone app. If I delete my example iPhone app it says "page cannot be displayed" after Facebook login. How do I get Facebook to redirect to my real iPhone app after login (just take me back to the iPhone app that I came from)?

Comment: Did you set the proper URL in your Info.plist?

Comment: I thought I did but apparently I didn't

Comment: Ok I set the proper URL and now half the time it redirects to my real iphone app and half the time to my test app, even though I am always coming from my real app.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to any url after login with facebook, you can append redirect_uri param to login url : 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...

Comment: But I don't have a website, I have an app

Comment: Hi @curtis, I don't really get what you mean. If it is a client flow, after you display the popup for user to login to Facebook, Facebook will return a redirect. And can just intercept the redirect and take the parameter from the redirect url in your app.

Comment: When the user logs in to facebook they are in safari. I need safari to return focus to my app. My app is minimized when they are logging in to Facebook. It never gets control back. I can have facebook redirect to a url in safari but my ios app is not on the internet.

Comment: Hi, is it an option for you to open the login popup in the web view controlled by your client App ? Using the UiWebView. http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/